# how to obtain guava jar for command line usage

Tags: java, guava

I would like to load the Guava library to make use of it via a command prompt in Windows. I can only locate information on how to use Guava with Maven and Eclipse, but nothing about how to do it just via command prompt. I also cannot determine where to obtain the JAR file.

Comment: Guava isn't usable as a command line utility... What are you asking,exactly?

Comment: And JAR file is very available on their wiki page. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume, by command line you mean `javac`. I've just UTFG "maven guava" and it took me to [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/19.0). From there on, you can navigate to the current version (22 as of now) and download it manually. There are more such repositories and most of them contain all usually used JAR files.